# Laravel date validation erroring for string "today"

Tags: php, laravel, datetime, laravel-validation

I'm using laravel validation for a date field like this:

```
Validator::make($shipment, [
            'collection_date' => 'required|date',
    ...
```

and I'm sending json with this field:

```
"collection_date": "today",
```

It's giving this error:

```
{
    "collection_date": [
        "The collection date is not a valid date."
    ]
}
```

Now, you might say DUH, that's not a valid datestring, but the problem is this:

Every source I can find explaining how the "date" validator works in Laravel says it uses PHP's internal strtotime function. `strtotime("today")` spits out a timestamp corresponding to Today (specifically, 00:00 this morning). That being the case, "today" should be seen as a valid "date" by laravel, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel use parse_date() underhood is not using strtotime() function
You can check the [validateDate](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/65f00dde474a267cdb84a311a88018c50d1c83fe/src/Illuminate/Validation/Concerns/ValidatesAttributes.php#L519-L536) function for more info
If you want to use your rule you can go with that

```php
$validator = Validator::make($shipment, [
    'collection_date' => [
        'required',
        function (string $attribute, mixed $value, Closure $fail) {
            if (strtotime($value) === false) {
                $fail("The {$attribute} is invalid.");
            }
        },
    ],
])
```

Or you can make your [own rule validation](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#using-rule-objects)

If you are not satisfied with date rule you can override it by extending the Validator

```php
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        Validator::extend('date', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
            return !!strtotime($value);
        });
    }
}

// Then

$validator = Validator::make($shipment, [
    'collection_date' => [
        'required',
        'date'
    ],
])
```

Comment: Thank you for the link to validateDate, I see what's happening now. It's using strtotime at one stage, but it's also using `$date = date_parse($value);` and then the `checkdate` function -- so the reason 'today' is failing is because `date_parse('today')` doesn't work out. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The validator is treating the 'today' sent in the json as a string and not a validate date format.
When using the date rule, Laravel expects the field value to be in a format that directly represents a date, such as "Y-m-d" (e.g., "2023-10-31") or "m/d/Y" (e.g., "10/31/2023"). While PHP's strtotime function is forgiving and interprets "today" correctly, Laravel's date rule does not consider such string representations as valid date formats.

```
"collection_date": "2023-10-31",
```

Comment: so why is it that all these places online say that laravel's date rule literally uses 'strtotime' to check if it's a valid date? is that not correct? What does laravel's date rule use to validate a date format?

Comment: Laravel date validation rule primarily relies on PHP's strtotime function to validate a date string. It is supposed to check if a given string can be interpreted as a valid date by PHP.

However, there might be inconsistencies or differences in the way "today" or other relative time strings are interpreted by strtotime and the way the Laravel date rule interprets them.

Comment: if there are inconsistencies, then it can't just be simply the case that Laravel's date rule uses strtotime - it must be doing something different, or in addition to, strtotime. So... what is it? What is the 'date' validator doing?

Answer (score -2):

```
 $jsonData = [
        [
            'collection_date' => Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d'),
        ],

        // Add more data as needed
    ];
```